# CSS combine :not with :last-of-type

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to select the last `<li>` element that is not hidden. I tried this:

```
li:not([hidden]):last-of-type
```

which doesn't give any error, but also doesn't do what I want. It gives the `<li>` that is both the last `<li>` at it's level (`:last-of-type`) AND not hidden, while I want to select the last from among the non-hidden ones, even if it is not the actual last in it's level. Anyone know how to do this? (CSS preferable, but JS also acceptable. jQuery is not acceptable)

Comment: `doesn't give any error` - does CSS ever give any error?

Comment: create a fiddle or snippet need to know why you have used `:not([hidden])`

Comment: @matewka: Sure it does, in the developer console.

Comment: @BoltClock Not every browser can do that. I know that IE10< accepts and shows anything as a correct style. Opera 12.17 shows this kind of error, but I can't seem to find the equivalent on 15+ and other Webkit/Blink based browsers. On firefox, I'm almost sure it does.

Comment: @BoltClock, you're right. But it's not gonna _stop the reset of the CSS_. I've always treated it more like: "oh! This is an invalid statement. We're not gonna use it but will proceed with the rendering".

Answer (score 2):

There are several questions about this on SO. `last-of-type` refers to the last element of a given type, period, full stop. It does NOT refer to the last element which matches some set of conditions such as class, or attribute.

There are some proposals to do what you want that we may see in the distant future, but for now, you cannot do this.

The alternatives are

1. Add a special class wherever the HTML is generated showing the one you want to do something with
2. Use a different HTML element for the ones you want to do `last-of-type` on, but in this case you're stuck because `<ul>` and `<ol>` elements can only have children of `<li>` or other `<ul>`s and `<ol>`s
3. Write some JS to ferret out the element you want

Comment: #2 seems quite out of the question considering these are `li` elements we're dealing with.

Comment: Yeah, but my point was that in most cases it's not valid for `li`s to have siblings of other element types.